# Installing oci8 on Centos 8 running Apache and php-fpm

Tags: php, oracle, apache, centos8, instantclient

I have oracle instantclient 19.3 installed and can see that OCI8 is loaded in PHP from a terminal by running php -m.  I also added LD_LIBRARY_PATH and ORACLE_HOME and environment variables to /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf.  They show up correctly in the environment section in phpinfo.

However, oci8 still does not show loading from apache.

Any suggestions on what else I can try to get this to work?

Comment: CLI and FPM are likely using two different configuration files. Run `phpinfo()` via a page served by apache to see what config file it's loading. You shouldn't need either LD_LIBRARY_PATH or ORACLE_HOME in your live Apache environment, those are only used when compiling the module.

Comment: What config file am I looking for in phpinfo?  I assume you are meaning /etc/php.ini?  If I run php -m -c /etc/php.ini then oci8 shows up.  Just not in Apache and that is the config file that is loading in Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Miracle of miracles.  Oracle has a specific instaclient for Linux 8. You can download it here.  https://www.oracle.com/cis/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html

Installing that driver took care of the problem.  Wahoo ;)

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` must be set before a process starts.

On Oracle Linux 8 / RHEL 8 I found that I needed to edit `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` and add:

```
env[LD_LIBRARY_PATH] = /usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I had installed the Oracle Instant Client RPMs packages; change the path to suit your library location.

I also disabled SELinux with `setenforce permissive` to avoid the error `ORA-12546: TNS:permission denied`.  (Update: note the comment below about using `audit2allow`)

When using Instant Client, you should not set `ORACLE_HOME`.

Comment: I read somewhere that centos 8 no longer uses /etc/sysconfig/httpd.

Comment: I've updated the answer.  Centos 8 is probably similar to RHEL 8.   This seems similar to what you tried, so triple check you have everything correct, and have restarted the php-fpm service.

Comment: still no dice... 

removed ORACLE_HOME from /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf. 
added env[LD_LIBRARY_PATH] = /usr/lib/oracle/19.3/client64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
reloaded php-fpm:  systemctl reload php-fpm
restarted apache: apachectl restart
From Apache Environment shows:
LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib/oracle/19.3/client64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Yet running php -m from a shell prompt shows oci8 is loaded

Comment: I had to revert back to Centos 7 for it to work ;(

Comment: Ugh, don't use `setenforce permissive` and allow anything to run. Run `audit2allow` and generate an appropriate permissions policy to allow it to run.